# iOS UISearchDisplayController doesn't show results

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a problem with `UISearchDisplayController`. I added a UITableView to `UIViewController` using `Storyboard`. `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` are connected to myViewController in Storyboard.

I implemented following `delegates` and `datasources` in myViewController:

`UISearchBarDelegate`, `UISearchDisplayDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`, `UITableViewDelegate`.
Showing all of data in table view works fine, but when I start searching, `numberOfRowsInSection`: method is called but after that `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: isn't called, and the `searchResultsTableView` isn't displayed at all. 
Can someone help me?

Below is code of `UISearchDisplayDelegate` and `UISearchBarDelegate` methods.

***EDIT:***

```c
static NSString *ProductCellIdentifier = @"TKMProductTableCell";
@interface TKMSearchAllProductsTableVC () <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate> {
    UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *allProducts;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *filteredProducts;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchBar *searchBar;

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [_filteredProducts count];
    } else {
        return [_allProducts count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TKMProductTableCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ProductCellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    [self configureProductCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath inTableView:tableView];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureProductCell:(TKMProductTableCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath inTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    TKMProduct *product = nil;
    if (tableView == searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        product = self.filteredProducts[indexPath.row];
    } else {
        product = self.allProducts[indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.lblTitle.text = product.name;

}
#pragma mark - UISearchBarDelegate
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:nil];
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;

    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

    [searchDisplayController setActive:YES animated:YES];
}

-(void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;
}

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = NO;

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    [searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayDelegate

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self.filteredProducts removeAllObjects];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", searchText];
    _filteredProducts = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[_allProducts filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}

- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
    {
    if (![searchString isEqualToString:@""] && searchString != nil) {
        [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString];
        [searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setHidden:NO];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

***EDIT 2***

This is my code for UISearchDisplayController:

```
searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_searchBar contentsController:self];
searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

Here is screenshoot of storyboard connections:
[screenshoot of storyboard connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpnFv.png)

***EDIT 3:***

I've just found in Logs that `UITableView's` frame is `CGRectZero` in `numberOfRowsInSection` method:

```
(lldb) po [searchDisplayController searchResultsTableView]
<UISearchResultsTableView: 0x1368c4a00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1744420d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x174821e20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}>

(lldb) po [self.searchDisplayController searchResultsTableView]
<UISearchResultsTableView: 0x1368c4a00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1744420d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x174821e20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}>

(lldb) po self.tableView
<UITableView: 0x136878e00; frame = (0 0; 320 504); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x17444dd70>; layer = <CALayer: 0x17422e300>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 117906}>

(lldb) po tableView
<UISearchResultsTableView: 0x1368c4a00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1744420d0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x174821e20>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}>
```

Comment: Could you show me the code you have written in UISearchBarDelegates and UISearchDislplayDelegates methods

Comment: I've just added a code.

Answer (score 1):

### Suggestion

I may be a little bit off topic but you should know this.

Don't use `UISearchDisplayController` because it won't be stable anymore.

**Apple Documentation**

> Important: UISearchDisplayController is deprecated in iOS 8. (Note
> that UISearchDisplayDelegate is also deprecated.) To manage the
> presentation of a search bar and display search results in iOS 8 and
> later, instead use UISearchController.

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/index.html)

Comment: Just because something is deprecated doesn't mean it's not stable.

Comment: @Lefteris who said it isn't stable, I said it will not adapt architectural  changes on devices both of Hardware and Software. Shortly Apple will not support this class anymore, and as a result soon there will be bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check what numberOfRowsInSection returns. also check _filteredProducts array size after filterContentForSearchText method execute inside shouldReloadTableForSearchString method. put NSLog inside each method and debug the code.

Try this NSPredicate format string:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like[cd] %@", searchText];
```

Comment: Yes, I checked it with breakpoints in numberOfRowsInSection: method and size of _filteredProducts is correct. Filterring works fine.

Comment: The `searchResultsTableView` isn't displayed at all.

Comment: May be object reference is not correct for "searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView".
Also make sure all connections in storyboard for data source and delegates for tableviewcontroller and searchviewcontroller. please mention where you have sets reference for searchDisplayController object in your code. check all connection and delegate for searchDisplayController object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered the class or the custom cell nib to the `UISearchDisplayController` Table?

I do in that `UISearchDisplayController` delegate method:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
  didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    [tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class]
      forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't give any effect.